# Swift: How to change imageView color to look like it was tapped?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an imageView inside of a cell. However, when I tap it that cell, there aren't any visual indicators that it was tapped. I want it to look the same as an imageView inside a button, where it changes colors when you tap the button.

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    // what do i do with the cell.imageView to change it's state to look like it was tapped?
  }
```

Comment: That's kind of vague. You need to _specify_ what you want to have happen.

Comment: Did you try adding background image to a UIButton instead of using UIImageView?

Comment: Answered my own question. Just had to change the alpha so that it fades away when you press it

Comment: BTW, unlike tableview cells, collectionview cells don't have `imageView` by default.

Comment: yeh my fault i left out that I made a custom class to inherit from uicollectionviewcell and added an outlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    let cell: IconCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! IconCell
    cell.imageView.alpha = 0.5
    return true
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell: IconCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! IconCell
    cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0
  }
```